# C# Populate dynamically nested Dictionary with unknown depth

Tags: c#, dictionary

I get an array of Nodes and a Value into my Method which have to be nested into a Dictionary Structure. But I really need help with the logic here.

I did a static Test which shows what I need:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> CreateNestedDictionary(string[] chainNodes, string value)
{
    // Testvalues:
    // ["application", "deepNode", "evenDeeperNode"], "Value"
    var container = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    container.Add("application", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "deepNode", new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"evenDeeperNode", "Value" } }}});

    return container;
 }
```

So basically, I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` variable, which can contain an infinite number of Dictionaries of the same type. At the very end, I need a `Dictionary<string, string>` to define the last node and the value.
By Node I mean the Key of the Dictionary. Those will later be represented in a JSON Sctructure.

The thing is, that I don't know how many Elements I get in `chainNodes`. Also, I may have to call this Method several times and add more Nodes. I would then have several chainNodes which have to go into the same Dictionary structure. Iwould then have to make sure that the Keys stay unique.

Is there any easy way to populate this structure dynamically? Or even a LINQ approach that deals with this?
Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you in advance

### Update

After the comments I realized I did a really bad job explaining this.
Here is another example:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> CreateNestedDictionary(string[] chainNodes, string value)
{
    // Testvalues:
    // ["application", "deepNode", "evenDeeperNode"], "Value"
    var container = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chainNodes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != chainNodes.Length -1)
        {
            container.Add(chainNodes[i], new Dictionary<string, object>()); // fill this empty Dictionary
        }
        else
        {
            container.Add(chainNodes[i], value);
        }

    }
}
```

Adding the last Dictionary is easy but I don't know how to fill the Dictionaries after the first.

Comment: That's not a very good way to implement this datastructure. You lose type-safety (`object`). But you *are* populating it dynamically, so I don't know what your question is exactly.

Comment: You are going to need to iterate over `chainNodes` and special case the last element.

Comment: In the above example I use a simple Add with three Dictionaries.
But it is possible that chainNodes contains 4 or more Strings which all have to be added using a Dictionary<string, object> into the container. I don't know how I can add these into my container dynamically

Comment: Wouldn't a data structure solve your problem?

Comment: I tried editing the question.
This is what you meant by iterating over chainNodes.  The first and last Add is simple. But after the First Add (adding the first key and another dictionary) I need to add the next key into the newly created Dictionary. I can't just Add to the container now. I really am confused about this...

Comment: I suggest that you create a class(nested if needed) for representing the elements in your chainNode instead of a Dictionary. The fact that you don't know how many elements you get in chainNodes puts you in the possibility that you can't add keys later that already exists in the Dictionary. Well, unless you are certain that every element you get is unique. Also, it will be easier to serialize to JSON as you mentioned, once you have your class structure defined.

Comment: But how do I create such a class? This Class would have every Element in chainNodes as Property right? But those are unknown. I read about ExpandoObject but couldn't think of a way to implement it with the nested behaviour.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your data looks like. But based on your comment you can have a `ChainNode` class, which has a `List<Element> elements` property. Well, `Element` is also another class, if there are further nodes under `Element`, again you could represent them as another `List<ChildElement> childElements` property.

Comment: @jmc Okay I will try working in that direction to find a cleaner solution for this. Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood this correctly: `chainNodes` is a list of the names, and `value` goes in the deepest dictionary (with name `chainNodes[chainNodes.Length-1]`).

Summary: you need to iterate and special case the deepest node.

Something recursive is probably easiest, starting with the pure creation case (no need to check for existing entries).

```
 public Dictionary<string, object> CreateNestedDictionary(string[] chainNodes, object value) {
   return DoCreate(chainNodes, value, 0);
 }

 private Dictionary<string, object> DoCreate(string[] chainNodes, object value, int index) {
   var res = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   if (index == chainNodes.Length - 1) {
     // Bottom out the recursion
     res.Add(chainNodes[index], value);

   } else {
      res.Add(chainNodes[index], DoCreate(chainNodes, value, index+1));
   }
   return res;
 }
```

Recursion naturally allows you to special case that last string because that is the end case that recursion must have.

For the adding to an existing collection case, you need to change the recursion to:

- Pass down the current node
- Check if `chainNodes[index]` key exists and use that entry or create a new one.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. I will test this.

Comment: Since this is the solution I was looking for I will mark this as the answer. The structure might be poor but as long at it works it doesn't seem to be a problem. Thanks everyone for helping me out here! :)

Comment: @AmenoKenshi I am sure there are better data structures, but any update/lookup is going to be iterative because inevitably that better data structure will incorporate some form of graph. What would be a better data structure would need far more context: what kind of higher level operations are needed? (Higher level: those that make use of update/add/… low level operations.)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm only working on this Method and only know, that the Database contains two String with the format I mentioned earlier. Splitting the first gives me the chainedNode Array, the second is the value. I want to use this Structure of Dictionaries to generate a JSON String. @jmc mentioned a solution using classes which I will look into now. But your solution works so far. But I will have to do some changes since I will need one big Dictionary using different chainNodes.
To get back to the structure: I think this solution is okay for now, since I'm not sure of the operations needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I implemented infinite nesting Dictionaries.
My structure is: `Dict([bool],object)`, ending with `[bool] = true`.

```
        public void Init(bool[] boolArray)
        {
            BoolDict = new Dictionary<bool, object>();
            Dictionary<bool, object> parent = BoolDict;
            for (int index = 0; index < boolArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (index < boolArray.Length - 1)
                {
                    Dictionary<bool, object> nestedDict = new Dictionary<bool, object>();
                    parent.Add(boolArray[index], nestedDict);
                    parent = nestedDict;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Add(boolArray[index], true);
                }
            }
        }
```

It's important to save the new Dict as the parent so that you can add to the new parent which you created in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the first value from the `chainNodes` and recursively call the method if there are any more values until you reach the end.

I'm with @Blorgbeard, though in that, this is a poor structure.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> CreateNestedDictionary(string[] chainNodes, string value)
{
    // Testvalues:
    // ["application", "deepNode", "evenDeeperNode"], "Value"
    var key = chainNodes.First();
    chainNodes = chainNodes.Skip(1).ToArray();
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { key, chainNodes.Any() ? CreateNestedDictionary(chainNodes, value) : value } };    
}
```

Comment: What would be a better structure for this? The thing is, that I get my Data from a Database, where the layers are separated by dots. So I get: `"application.deepnode.evendeepernode"` and `"value"` from the database. Which is already a weird approach.